# Давайте разберем вопросы с метками про консоль, терминал и командную строку

Tags: обсуждение, статус-запланировано, синонимы-меток, замена-меток

Есть ряд меток: [консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c), [console](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console), [терминал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb), [terminal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal), [consoleapplication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consoleapplication). Они обычно относятся к одной из двух тем:

- Вопросы о скриптах командной строки: [shell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), реже [cmd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd).exe
- Вопросы о разработке приложения, которое работает через stdin/stdout, в том числе через ручной ввод данных.
- Вопросы об использовании таких приложений (разные VCS, утилиты *nix и т.п.)

Хорошо бы пройтись по вопросам.

- Те, где первая группа, поменять на соответствующую конкретную метку.
- А для второй группы нужно выбрать центральную метку и остальные к ней синонимизировать.
- Вопросы третьей группы вообще не должны иметь ни одной из этих меток, нужно заменить на метку конкретного приложения. Если таковой нет — пишите тут в комментариях, обсудим.

Мои ресурсы ограничены, поэтому призываю всех принять участие. =)

Comment: Ещё есть bash )

Comment: С башем-то как раз и так все ясно. А консолетерминалы и cmd валят в одну кучу.

Comment: предлагаю «центральной» сделать метку *tui* (она, кстати, один раз использовалась) — *text user interface*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ни разу не встречал, мне гораздо более знакомо *cli - command line interface*. Есть какое-то различие между этими понятиями?

Comment: > Есть какое-то различие между этими понятиями? — например: «текстовый интерфейс» может быть построен и без «командной строки». например, с помощью меню. в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F), вроде бы, неплохо изложено.

Comment: *tui*, м.б. и неплохо, но у меня эта аббревиатура ни с чем (кроме турфирмы) не ассоциируется, боюсь у других тоже.

Comment: @avp , в таких случаях как раз и помогает краткое описание метки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, как-то мне кажется, что немногие относятся к  меткам настолько серьезно, чтобы еще и читать их описания (даже когда они высвечиваются при наведении мыши).

Comment: @avp , цитирую из вопроса: «А для второй группы нужно выбрать центральную метку и остальные к ней **синонимизировать**». вот я и предложил вариант такой «центральной» метки.

Comment: @avp , *у меня эта аббревиатура ни с чем (кроме турфирмы) не ассоциируется* — а аббревиатура *gui* тоже ни с чем не ассоциируется?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, *gui* ассоциируется (graphical user interface), а вот *tui* -- нет. О чем и сообщил, подозревая, что буду не одинок в этом. Что именно взять в качестве **центральной метки** -- не знаю, из упомянутых в вопросе *terminal* мне бы понравилась больше остальных, но очевидно, что и она недостаточно хороша в данном контексте.