# Объединить метки [консоль] и [console]

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c) и [console](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console) в сторону русскоязычной. [Описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/console/info) находится в стадии утверждения.

Comment: [Давайте разберем вопросы с метками про консоль, терминал и командную строку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1961/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83), запланировано, ха-ха.

Comment: @NickVolynkin закрываем тогда мой как дубликат и решаем проблему более комплексно как в Вашем вопросе?